# Trying to add 'Average' and 'Remarks', cannot complete logic

Tags: arrays, c, math

I'm doing self-studying, and I'm at a point where I can do menus in C.  I am trying to add 'Average' and 'Remarks' though in my arrays where:

- Average = (quiz1+quiz2+quiz3)/3.0, and
- Remarks = If 75.00 and above = Passed, Else 74.99 and below = Failed

But I cannot yield the correct logic.

Please help review my code and see how I can insert.  Thanks in advance for your advice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 3

char name[MAX][31];
int quiz1[MAX]; int q1[MAX];
int quiz2[MAX]; int q2[MAX];
int quiz3[MAX]; int q3[MAX];
int last;

int initialize();//initialize parallel arrays
void add(char n[31], int q1, int q2, int q3);
void del(char n[31]);
void display();
int search(char n[31]);
int isfull();
int isempty();
int menu();//one entry one exit

int main(){
    char nm[31];
    int q1,q2,q3,m;
    initialize();
    while(1){
        m=menu();
        switch(m){
        case 1 : 
            system("cls");
            printf("Insert Mode\n");
            printf("Input Student Name: ");scanf("%s",nm);
            printf("Input Quiz1: ");scanf("%d",&q1);
            printf("Input Quiz2: ");scanf("%d",&q2);
            printf("Input Quiz3: ");scanf("%d",&q3);
            add(nm,q1,q2,q3);
            break;
        case 2 : 
            system("cls");
            printf("Delete Mode\n");
            printf("Input Student Name: ");scanf("%s",nm);
            del(nm);
            break;
        case 3 : 
            display();
            break;
        case 4 : exit(0);
        default: 
            printf("Please select an option between 1-4 only\n");
            system("pause");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

int initialize(){
    last = -1;
}

void add(char n[31], int q1, int q2, int q3){
    if (isfull()){
        printf("Array is full!.\n");
        system("pause");
    }
    else{
        last = last+1;
        strcpy(name[last],n);
        quiz1[last]=q1; quiz2[last]=q2; quiz3[last]=q3;
    }
}

void del(char n[31]){
    int i,p;
    if (isempty()){
        printf("Array is empty.\n");
        system("pause");
    }
    else{
        p=search(n);
        if (p==-1){
            printf("Not found.\n");
            system("pause");
        }
        else {
            for (i=p;i<last;i++){
                strcpy(name[i],name[i+1]);
                quiz1[i]=quiz1[i+1]; quiz2[i]=quiz2[i+1]; quiz3[i]=quiz3[i+1];
            }
            last--;
        }
    }
}

int search(char n[31]){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=last;i++)
        if (strcmp(name[i],n)==0)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

void display(){
    int i;
    system("cls");
    printf("No.\tStudent\tQuiz1\tQuiz2\tQuiz3\n");
    for(i=0;i<=last;i++)
        printf("%d.)\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",i+1,name[i],quiz1[i],quiz2[i],quiz3[i]);
    system("pause");
}

int menu(){
    int op;
    system("cls");
    printf("Menu\n");
    printf("1.) Add Student record\n");
    printf("2.) Delete Student record\n");
    printf("3.) Display\n");
    printf("4.) Exit\n");
    printf("Select(1-4): ");
    scanf("%d",&op);
    return(op);
}

int isfull(){
    return(last==MAX-1);
}

int isempty(){
    if (last==-1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You're not having any trouble with the code that displays the menu or adds and removes students, so it should be removed from the question.

Comment: Try adding the line `average = (quiz1[i]+quiz2[i]+quiz3[i])/3.0` somewhere appropriate, and then, adding `average` to the appropriate `printf`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the code with the error while I'm doing trial-and-error.  My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several pieces of advice:

1. Consistent indentation and formatting is your friend, and it will make it easier for others to read and debug your code.  Right now your formatting is a bit of a mess (which I see Barmar has cleaned up - thanks Barmar).

   Avoid using globals where you can - ideally, functions should only communicate through parameters and return values, rather than sharing some global state.

   Anytime you find yourself creating a bunch of variables with the same type and same name with some ordinal (`q1`, `q2`, `q3`), that's a real strong hint that you want to use an *array*.

   Instead of using parallel arrays, create a `struct` type to associate a student's name with their quiz scores:

   ```
   #define MAX_NAME_LEN 30
   #define NUM_QUIZZES 3

   struct Student {
     char name[MAX_NAME_LEN+1]; 
     int quiz[NUM_QUIZZES]; 
   };
   ```

   and then you can create an array of this type:

   ```
   struct Student students[MAX];
   ```

   Write separate functions to handle input as well as output, such as

   ```
   void getStudent( struct student *newStudent )
   {
     printf( "Input Student Name: " );
     if ( !fgets( newStudent->name, sizeof newStudent->name, stdin ) )
       // error on input, handle as appropriate

     for ( size_t i = 0; i < NUM_QUIZZES; i++ )
     {
       printf( "Input Quiz%d: ", i+1 );
       if ( scanf( "%d", &newStudent->quiz[i] ) != 1 )
         // error on input, handle as appropriate
     }
   }
   ```

   which you would call like so:`int main( void )
   {
     struct Students[MAX];
     int last = 0;
     ...
     while( 1 )
     {
       switch( menu() )
       {
         case 1:
           if ( last + 1 < MAX )
             getStudent( &students[last++] );
           else
             // array is full
           break;`

   You can compute and display the average and remark as part of your `display` function:

   ```
   void display( struct Student *students, size_t numStudents )
   {
     /**
      * Print out the header - since we're using an array for the number
      * of quizzes, we'll print each quiz header in a loop.
      *
      * As a matter of personal taste, I'm putting the quiz average
      * and remarks before the individual quiz scores.  This will introduce
      * some inefficiency below, and you certainly don't have to do it this
      * way.  But it will illustrate how to insert your computed values into
      * the output.  
      */
     printf( "No.\tStudent\tAvg\tRemarks" );
     for ( size_t i = 0; i < NUM_QUIZZES; i++ )
       printf("\tQuiz%zu", i );
     putchar('\n');
     /**
      * Loop through each student
      */
     for ( size_t i = 0; i < numStudents; i++ )
     {
       /**
        * Compute the average
        */
       double sum = 0.0;
       for ( size_t j = 0; j < NUM_QUIZZES; j++ )
         sum += students[i].quizzes[j];
       double avg = sum / NUM_QUIZZES;
       /**
        * Print everything up to the quiz scores
        */
       printf( "%zu\t%s\t%.2f\t%s", i, students[i].name, avg, avg >= 75.00 ? "Passed" : "Failed");
       /**
        * Print the quiz scores - yes, this is a bit inefficient since we're
        * looping through the quiz array twice.  This is an artifact of wanting
        * to display the average and remarks first.  
        */
       for ( size_t j = 0; j < NUM_QUIZZES; j++ )
         printf( "\t%d", students[i].quiz[j] );
       putchar( '\n' );
     }
   }
   ```

   which you would call from your `main` function as

   ```
   case 3:
     display( students, MAX );
   ```

I realize there's some stuff that looks weird or inconsistent; welcome to C programming.